# IllegalStateException in Timer with ASyncTask

Tags: java, android

i want to run a Background ASycTask every few minutes. I created a timer and i execute the .execute command of the Background Task.  I also created a bool `isChecking` which is true while the BackgroundNotify is running. The problem is that i still get the following error:

```
01-26 15:09:32.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22332): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
01-26 15:09:32.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22332): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)
01-26 15:09:32.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22332):    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:578)
01-26 15:09:32.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22332):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
01-26 15:09:32.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22332):    at de.tecfriends.vbtsplash2013.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:61)
01-26 15:09:32.871: E/AndroidRuntime(22332):    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An AsyncTask can only be executed once. If you need to execute the task again, create a new instance, and call `execute()` on that:

```
if (task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
    task = new AsyncTask();
}

if (task.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
    task.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as in log :

> llegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been
>   executed (a task can be executed only once)

means you are trying to start ASycTask which is already running . you will need to check wether ASycTask is running or not before starting it  using [AsyncTask.Status](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html) :

```
if(your_AsyncTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
    // My AsyncTask is running  
}
if(your_AsyncTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
    // My AsyncTask is FINISHED . start here again 
}
```